# IBExpert Database Designer Table Relationships

Tags: relationship, ibexpert

Assuming I have this 2 tables:

[image]

I want to keep the address information in a sepparate table `Address`, because not always the person's address is known, therefore, in this case, there will not be a corresponding entry in the `Address` table for that particular person.
Hence, the relationship between `Person` and `Address` should be one-to-zero or one.

However, I could not find how to create a one-to-zero or one relationship between to tables using `IBExpert Database Designer`.

Also I did not see in the interface any option to specify indentifying and non identifying relationship.

Hope someone can help me through this issue.